# Как в Go получить разность между двумя датами?

Tags: golang, время

Как, имея две даты, получить разность между ними в минутах?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Например с помощью [`Sub`](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Time.Sub):

```
t1 := time.Date(2017, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, time.UTC)
t2 := time.Date(2017, 1, 1, 0, 15, 0, 0, time.UTC)
fmt.Println(int(t2.Sub(t1) / time.Minute))
// 15
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/uehzV_7Z_Y.

Comment: А нельзя ли посчитать в днях разницу между датами а не в минутах секундах? Не нашел простого вычитания одной даты из другой как во многих языках.

Answer (score 2):

или с помощью [Unix](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Time.Unix) :

```
t1 := time.Date(2017, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, time.UTC)
t2 := time.Date(2017, 1, 1, 0, 15, 0, 0, time.UTC)
firstTime := t1.Unix()
secondTime := t2.Unix()
deltaMinute := (secondTime - firstTime ) / 60
fmt.Println(deltaMinute)
//15
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/g6Tbv6b2nS